# CMake to run script

Tags: python, cmake

I am trying to create a CMake build that will run several python scripts before building software, if at all.  As a starting point, I wanted to create a CMake project that would only run a single python script.  I am having trouble getting the script to execute.  Here is what I have in my project.

test.py

```py
open('script_output.txt', 'a').close()
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (module)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT script_output.c
           COMMAND python test.py)

add_custom_target(release ALL DEPENDS script_output.c)
```

It seems to try and run Visual Studio compiler, which I don't want and does not run python script `script_output.py`, which I do want.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code suddenly terminates on the last line without closing bracket (`)`). Could you complete that line?

Comment: sorry about that.  i updated it.

Comment: "It seems to try and run Visual Studio compiler" - You mean, when CMake **configures** the project, it checks the compilers but does not run your script? It is correct, as `project()` by default enables languages C and C++, and custom target and commands are executed at **build** stage, not on *configure* stage.

Comment: so how would i get CMake to only run the script in this example.  I am trying to understand how i can disable the default behavior of CMake to run a C build here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `add_custom_command` will run during your code compilation (after CMake completes), `execute_process` will run during the CMake configuration stage.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

# Skip compiler check by enabling no languages.
project(TestProj NONE)

# Tell CMake to run python from the directory where this CMakeLists file exists.
execute_process(COMMAND python test.py
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

# If you have more than one script to run, use a 
# separate execute_process command, to ensure sequential execution.
execute_process(COMMAND python test2.py
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
```

Additionally, you can specify `RESULT_VARIABLE` or `OUTPUT_VARIABLE` with the [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) command to set CMake variables based on the return codes or standard output from the executed process; this could be helpful for influencing subsequent CMake behavior.

Also, if you really want to disable CMake's initial compiler check, you can disable the languages by specifying `NONE` in the `project` command.

Comment: awesome, those where the answers i was looking for.  thanks!

Comment: I had one more question on this.  If i wanted to run 2 scripts, how do i ensure one runs before the other. Do i use a dependency?

Comment: @wolverine99 I updated the answer to address your question. To execute multiple scripts, use separate `execute_process` commands to preserve their order of execution.